# Is it incorrect to say "...it's not, is it? Or is it?"

Tags: phrases

The sentence I was thinking of is:

> Someone's blocked you in. It's not me, is it? Or is it?

It certainly reads oddly, but I've heard it used in general speech quite often.

As I understand it, the speaker is stating the question twice, firstly expecting the answer "no". Then secondly expecting the answer "yes".

Is the sentence grammatically incorrect? Something about it feels wrong.

Comment: it sounds redundant to me. Why not just "It's not me, or is it?"

Comment: I guess it is redundant. But it's still commonly used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be anything grammatically incorrect about this sentence. Perhaps the ellipsis of the words "really me" at the end of the sentence may make it sound dodgy:

> Someone's blocked you in. It's not me, is it? Or is it *really me*(who blocked you in)?

It's an entirely valid question, an entirely valid sentence structure. Perhaps a little informal.